# Problems with extending jQuery (adding debugging features)

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have the following jQuery extension method code, which provides all attributes of an element *as readable string* using `attrString()`:

### e.g.

```
$('div').attrString() returns "data-hello=Hello!, class=MyClass,"
```

### The current code looks like this:

```
// Return a debug string of all the attributes of an element (first if multiple elements)
jQuery.fn.attrString = function () {
    var result = "";
    if (this[0]) {
        $.each(this[0].attributes, function (i, attrib) {
            var name = attrib.name;
            var value = attrib.value;
            result += name + "=" + value + ", ";
        });
    }
    return result;
};
```

### and the tests are:

```
// Valid selection - multiple matches, multiple attributes
$('#output').append("<br/>$('div').attrString() = " + $('div').attrString());

// Valid selection - single attributes
$('#output').append("<br/>$('#output').attrString() = " + $('#output').attrString());

// Empty selection
$('#output').append("<br/>$().attrString() = " + $().attrString());
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8T38S/2/

### Questions:

- Is `if (this[0])` the correct way to test for an *empty* jQuery selection?
- Is there a more efficient way to concatenate the attribute names and values together
- and what is the simplest way to do this *without leaving a trailing comma* like it 
  currently does?
- Is there just a better way to do this already (e.g. property in the DOM somewhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. `if (this[0])` is one of the many ways to test if a jquery selection is not empty because, if it is empty, `this[0]` will be undefined, which evaluates to false in a boolean context. To concatenate the attribute names and values, jquery provides a `map` function. Use it like this:

```
// Returns an array: ["attr=value", "attr2=value2", etc.]
$.map(this[0].attributes, function (attrib, i) {
    var name = attrib.name;
    var value = attrib.value;
    return (name + "=" + value);
});
```

You can then use the `join` method to join them into a string. This will eliminate the trailing comma at the end. As for your last question, yes and no. If you are using this for debugging purposes, then you should use `console.log` or `console.dir`. This will print all properties of a certain object. However, if you would like to actually display it, then you should use the map function provided above.

http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/k9kLD/

The entire function is here:

```
// Return a debug string of all the attributes of an element (first if multiple elements)
jQuery.fn.attrString = function () {
    var result = "";
    if (this[0]) {
        result = $.map(this[0].attributes, function (attrib, i) {
            var name = attrib.name;
            var value = attrib.value;
            return (name + "=" + value);
        }).join(", ");
    }
    return result;
};
```

The rest of the code was unchanged.

Comment: Very helpful: suggest you put your JSFiddle code in the answer too, to make it complete. How efficient is `map`?

Comment: Also I simplified it to `return (attrib.name + "=" + attrib.value);` as temp variables *used one* seems wasteful :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie `$.map` is not that efficient i.e. not as efficient as a native `for` loop, but it is not that slow. If performance is really an issue, use a `for` loop, but you won't save but a millisecond at most. In addition, `$.map` is more readable.

Comment: Excellent. I have already replaced my version with yours in my utils js. Cheers :)